# react-native run-android :- error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up

Tags: android, react-redux, react-native

[Here is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eialh.png), pls go and check. it's my first project (I am using **Windows** 10). Whenever i try to run **react-native run-android** it's showing a error msg: **Android development path not found**. But when i run the Android studio and Open New Project and click on build button it's running fine. It's create a android build in **emulator** as well as in **my Own device**. But React Native not create a build.I check my **Environment Variables** also and i have set **ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, PATH**.

Comment: Firstly, you should run android emulator, before run this command => 'react-native run-android'

Comment: no @kablanfatih , it's not working :(